# Spring-Amqp-NET libraries for RabbitMQ - SSL support

Tags: spring-amqp

We want to use spring-amqp-net in our applications to listen for messages in RabbitMQ. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net-amqp

We couldn't figure out any configuration parameter for SSL connection neither in the source code nor in the documentation.

Does anybody now if spring-amqp-net supports SSL connection to RabbitMQ?

If yes, how can we configure the SSL connection in our .net application's Application.xml file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with .NET, or that project (I am the lead for the Java Spring AMQP project).

With the Java Spring AMQP library, SSL is configured by appropriately configuring the underlying RabbitConnectionFactory and then that instance is injected into the Spring CachingConnectionFacrtory.

Looking at the code, it appears a similar mechanism is available in the .NET library...

```
    public CachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory)
            : base(rabbitConnectionFactory) { }
```

whereby you can configure the underlying ConnectionFactory with SSL and provide it to the CachingConnectionFactory.

Comment: I have also seen that code in source code of spring-amqp-net. But I would like to know the necessary configuration parameters in spring-context xml, to enable SSL connection. For example, in spring-amqp java version, you can enable SSL connection by configuring the "useSSL" parameter as true. I'm looking for something similar in spring-amqp .NET version.  Is it possible to enable SSL communication only by configuration, without touching the source code?

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I don't know .NET - but it looks like you have to set `Ssl.Enabled = true;`. Or use a URI that starts with `amqps`. Look at the source code for the RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory`.